# Consider the following real $4\times 5$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> $$A = \left( \begin{array} { c c c c c } { 1 } & { 4 } & { 15 } & { 1
>  } & { - 9 } \\ { 0 } & { 1 } & { 4 } & { 0 } & { - 3 } \\ { 2 } & { -
>  4 } & { - 18 } & { - 1 } & { 15 } \\ { 1 } & { 0 } & { - 1 } & { 0 } &
>  { 2 } \end{array} \right)$$ Define a linear map $f _ { A } : \mathbb {
>  R } ^ { 5 } \rightarrow \mathbb { R } ^ { 4 }$ by $f _ { A } ( \mathbf
>  { v } ) = A v .$ Find a basis of the null space of $f _ { A }$ and a
>    basis of the image of $f _ { A } ,$ respectively.

So whether the rank of null space and the image is 5? If it is, how can I find the basis of null space and basis? This is the first time I try to solve a linear map with no n*n matrix, I am confused.

Comment: Terminology: There's no such thing as the "rank" of a subspace. The rank of a _matrix_ is the _dimension_ of the image. (Regarding how to do the problem: Surely earlier in the book/course they gave algorithms for finding bases for the nullspace and image (that is, the column space) of a matrix. If you skipped class that day look it up somewhere.)

Answer (score 2):

The procedure is exactly the same as for square matrices. I'll do a simpler example for the nullspace, see if you can apply the idea to your case. Let's try to find the nullspace for
$$ A=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&4\\1&1&1&4\\0&1&2&3\end{bmatrix}. $$
Do Gaussian Elimination to find the reduced row echelon form, $\operatorname{rref} A$. You should get
$$\operatorname{rref}A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1&-2\\0&1&2&3\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$
Now, put this in the form of equations. Say you have variables $w,x,y,z$, then $Ax=0$ (which is of course the system we want to consider since we're finding the nullspace of $A$) gives you the system
$$\begin{cases}w=y+2z;\\x=-2y-3z.\end{cases}$$
Therefore, the vectors $x$ satisfying $Ax=0$ are exactly those of the form $$\begin{bmatrix}y+2z\\-2y-3z\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=y\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}+z\begin{bmatrix}2\\-3\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$
But this tells you that the set $$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}2\\-3\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$ is a basis for the nullspace of $A$! We are done. Do the same steps with the different example in your case to get the desired solution.

Answer (score 1):

The null space is the set of vectors $v$, such that $f_A(v) = 0$. This means that you need to solve $Av = [0, 0, 0, 0]^T$. This amounts to Gaussian elimination. In this case, the echelon form of A is
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{rrrrr}
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 4 & 0 & -3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$
Let $v = [v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5]^T$. Solving $Av = 0$ means that
$$
\begin{cases}
v_1 - v_3 + 2v_5 = 0\\
v_2 + 4v_3 -3v_5 = 0\\
v_4 + v_5 = 0
\end{cases}
$$
If $Av = 0$, that means that 
$$
v = [v_3 - 2v_5, -4v_3 + 3v_5, v_3, -v_5, v_5]^T = v_3\cdot[1,-4,1,0,0]^T + v_5\cdot[-2,3,0,-1,1]^T
$$
The two vectors are the basis of the null space.